# How to change background-color on click?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to change the background color of the div tag when it is clicked, however I am unable to make it work.

.ts

```
goToHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
}
isHome() {
    return this.goToHome;
}
```

.html

```
<div [class.selected]="isHome()" (click)="goToHome()">
    <mat-icon class="icon-container"> home</mat-icon>
</div>
```

.scss

```
.selected {
    background-color: #ff3588;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `goToHome` is a function you return inside the `isHome` method. Instead return a boolean value

```
<div [class.selected]="isHomeSelected" (click)="goToHome()">
    <mat-icon class="icon-container"> home</mat-icon>
</div>

isHomeSelected = false
goToHome() {
    this.isHomeSelected = true;
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
}
```

Comment: The proper Angular way of inserting classes conditionally is by using `[ngClass]`

Comment: it's not a must to use `ngClass` every time. yes, it's an angular directive but you can also use `[class.]` since it also enforces the two-way binding. in here using this approach is much more simple.

Comment: @JonasPraem, ngClass is for overriding\ modifying the entire css class. But [class.selected] is more granular to choose whether 'selected' css class be added or not. Sachila Ranawaka is correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use `[ngClass]`, (assuming isHome() returns a boolean value)

```
<div [ngClass]="{'selected': isHome()}" (click)="goToHome()">
    <mat-icon class="icon-container"> home</mat-icon>
</div>
```

It applies classes conditionally.

Comment: no difference in functionality from what is there in the question

Comment: @SachinGupta we can only assume what is not provided. The ts file doesn't contain any logic. We can't debug that

Comment: @JonasPraem Then you should ask OP to clarify the question.

Comment: the only difference from OP and you code is `[class.selected]="isHome()"` replaced by `[ngClass]="{'selected': isHome()}"`. Both these things do the same work

Comment: This answer works if the provided assumption is implemented. It answers the title question.. i mean I could write `'selected': true` - but I don't think it adds anything